# Combine Multiple Boolean checks in VF Markup

Tags: apex, visualforce, parameters, global-variables

I want something like the below in my test to see of a `outputPanel` should be rendered

```
<apex:outputpanel rendered="{!recordType == 'System Change Request' & $currentPage().getParameters().get('mode') =='edit'}">
```

so if the recordType variable of the custom controller is 'System Change Request' **and** the *mode* of the page is set to `edit` then render the panel...

Unfortunately I must be getting it wrong as I am getting a syntax error

> Syntax error. Extra '.'

The reason I am trying to do this, is so that I can combine my *View* and *edit* pages in one VF Page, and just re-render the main panel when the user chooses to edit an existing record...

Or should I be using a variable in the controller that is set from the page parameters?

Comment: you should use variable in controller to set page parameter

Comment: Try `$CurrentPage.parameters.mode` for the syntax error...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use logical operators, and is `&&`, or is `||`. Note that the character occurs twice. However, it is probably cleaner in VF to use the `AND` and `OR` functions (e.g. `AND(condition1, condition2)` instead of `condition1 && condition2`. I mention this specifically because negation can look pretty awkward, compare `{!NOT(condition)}` with `{!!condition}`. The latter is far more confusing for me to read.

As mentioned in the comments, you are also incorrectly referencing page parameters, you should instead use `$CurrentPage.Parameters.mode` or cache it in `Apex` for simplicity.